# Declaring a function with variable size 2D array as input argument?

Tags: c, function

i have a 2D array whose size decided by some function. and now i want to pass the variable size 2D array to the input of some other function where func[constant_row_size][constant_column_size] are to mentioned but i want to make it variable.
how to do that?
Regards,
Ahamd

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [**About**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [**How to Ask a Question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Providing the necessary details, including your code, and associated errors, if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question.

Comment: basically a duplicate of Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10452921/how-to-work-with-a-2d-array-with-unknown-dimensions